# Output variable as html instead of string - PHP

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm working on Wordpress website. Here's code from my functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'listify_get_listing_to_array', function( $data, $listing ) {
    $cert = $listing->get_object()->_job_certificates;
    $desc = $listing->get_object()->_job_description;
    $price = $listing->get_object()->_job_price;
    $duration = $listing->get_object()->_trajanje_casa;
    $duration2 = $listing->get_object()->_job_duration;
  // Only add if our custom field is not empty.
  if ( '' !== $cert ) {
    $data['cert'] = $cert;
  }
  if ( '' !== $desc ) {
    $data['desc'] = $desc;
  }
  if ( '' !== $price ) {
    $data['price'] = $price;
  }
  if ( '' !== $duration ) {
    $data['duration'] = $duration;
  }
  if ( '' !== $duration2 ) {
    $data['duration2'] = $duration2;
  }

  // Return modified list of data.
  return $data;
}, 10, 2 );

add_action( 'listify_content_job_listing_meta', function() {
  // Check if available.

  //price/duraton
  echo '<# if ( data.duration && !data.duration2) { #>';

  echo '<div class="job_price_duration"><p><span class="job_price">{{data.price}}</span> / <span class="job_duration">{{data.duration}}</span></p></div>';

  echo '<# } #>';

  echo '<# if ( data.duration2 && !data.duration ) { #>';

  echo '<div class="job_price_duration"><p><span class="job_price">{{data.price}}</span> / <span class="job_duration">{{data.duration2}}</span></p></div>';

  echo '<# } #>';

  //certificate
  echo '<# if ( data.cert ) { #>';

  echo '<div class="job_certificates"><p>{{data.cert}}</p></div>';

  echo '<# } #>';

  //bio
  echo '<# if ( data.desc && !data.cert ) { #>';

  echo '<div class="job_description"><p>{{data.desc}}</p></div>';

  echo '<# } #>';

} );
```

The variables that output in html like this one:

```
  echo '<div class="job_certificates"><p>{{data.cert}}</p></div>';
```

show string instead of html. So for example if my variable (data.cert) was an actual html it will render it as string which is not correct. See screenshot:
[image]

Any suggestions on how to make this output as html instead of string?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you output the data variables directly to a log file? Also show the page source?

Comment: Not a Wordpress person, but from https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp.template, do you need to use {{{ }}} so that it doesn't escape the value.

Comment: @NigelRen, You're right. This helps a bit! Thanks!